# Facebook Login: No redirect, white page in popup

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a working Facebook-Login procedure using the PHP SDK. Now Facebook is requiring me to update my login flow since I apparently "violate the Facebook Platform Policies". According to them my "Login button doesn't properly reference Facebook." They suggest that "To fix this issue, you should always use our official SDK for Login." I suspect (but don't know for sure) this is because the login is not opened in a popup but rather in a new window using the PHP SDK getLoginUrl() method. Thus, I'm trying to update my Facebook Login flow.

In trying to combine the Javascript SDK (to render the official button and popup) with the PHP SDK (to handle the responses) I'm using the following approach (Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_access_token_from_javascript)

```
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="#" onClick="logInWithFacebook()">Log In with the JavaScript SDK</a></p>

<script>
  logInWithFacebook = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        alert('You are logged in &amp; cookie set!');
        // Now you can redirect the user or do an AJAX request to
        // a PHP script that grabs the signed request from the cookie.
      } else {
        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
    });
    return false;
  };
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'your-app-id',
      cookie: true, // This is important, it's not enabled by default
      version: 'v3.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When clicking the Login-Button a popup will show, as expected, to log me in. But...

- ...before I even enter my FB credentials the code alerts 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize'.
- ...after entering my credentials the popup remains open with a blank white page.
- ...when I click the button while already being logged in to Facebook I will only see a blank white page in the popup.
- ...there's no redirect (which I suppose has to be handled in the `if (response.authResponse)` part)

Comment: Log the response object to console inside the FB.login callback function, and check what it actually contains.

Comment: _“I suspect (but don't know for sure) this is because the login is not opened in a popup but rather in a new window using the PHP SDK getLoginUrl() method.”_ - I don’t think that should actually matter - although the server-side login flow is redirect-based, so usually handled in the current window, instead of a popup. _“trying to combine the Javascript SDK (to render the official button and popup)”_ - and where exactly are you doing that, rendering the official button? All I see is still a plain link inside a paragraph …